# MongoDB Aggregation check if array contains values

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following documents.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e9d9503853d3e2149fe6a22"),
    "Profitloss" : "PROFIT",
    "Remark" : null,
    "IsSelectedUser" : true,
    "UserList" : [ 
        ObjectId("5e9d2ba9853d3e2149fe6a07")
    ],
    "SenderId" : ObjectId("5e57a9477f8a1218849c9fc7"),
    "CreateDate" : ISODate("2020-04-20T12:26:43.725Z"),
    "ExitPrice" : 530,
    "FinalAmount" : 23160,
    "IsUpdate" : true,
    "LastModify" : ISODate("2020-04-20T12:56:23.794Z")
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e9d9503853d3e2149fe6a22"),
    "Profitloss" : "PROFIT",
    "Remark" : null,
    "IsSelectedUser" : true,
    "UserList" : [ 
        ObjectId("5e9d2ba9853d3e2149fe6a08")
        ObjectId("5e9d2ba9853d3e2149fe6a09")
    ],
    "SenderId" : ObjectId("5e57a9477f8a1218849c9fc7"),
    "CreateDate" : ISODate("2020-04-20T12:26:43.725Z"),
    "ExitPrice" : 530,
    "FinalAmount" : 23160,
    "IsUpdate" : true,
    "LastModify" : ISODate("2020-04-20T12:56:23.794Z")
}
```

Suppose my id is "5e57a9477f8a1218849c9fc7". so while fetching documents i want all the data but if in UserList array there was my id exists then i want to add 1 fields like "IsMyStatus" : true and if not exist then "IsMyStatus" : false. so the final output will be like this.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e9d9503853d3e2149fe6a22"),
    "Profitloss" : "PROFIT",
    "Remark" : null,
    "IsSelectedUser" : true,
    "UserList" : [ 
        ObjectId("5e9d2ba9853d3e2149fe6a07")
    ],
    "SenderId" : ObjectId("5e57a9477f8a1218849c9fc7"),
    "CreateDate" : ISODate("2020-04-20T12:26:43.725Z"),
    "ExitPrice" : 530,
    "FinalAmount" : 23160,
    "IsUpdate" : true,
    "LastModify" : ISODate("2020-04-20T12:56:23.794Z"),
    "IsMyStatus" : true

},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5e9d9503853d3e2149fe6a22"),
    "Profitloss" : "PROFIT",
    "Remark" : null,
    "IsSelectedUser" : true,
    "UserList" : [ 
        ObjectId("5e9d2ba9853d3e2149fe6a08")
        ObjectId("5e9d2ba9853d3e2149fe6a09")
    ],
    "SenderId" : ObjectId("5e57a9477f8a1218849c9fc7"),
    "CreateDate" : ISODate("2020-04-20T12:26:43.725Z"),
    "ExitPrice" : 530,
    "FinalAmount" : 23160,
    "IsUpdate" : true,
    "LastModify" : ISODate("2020-04-20T12:56:23.794Z"),
     "IsMyStatus" : false
}
```

Comment: Your sample / expected result is wrong, since "5e57a9477f8a1218849c9fc7" doesn't exists inside `UserList` in any documents. Please, provide valid sample

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      IsMyStatus: {
        $in: [
          ObjectId("5e57a9477f8a1218849c9fc7"),
          "$UserList"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WA8TIdYmRgD)